# How can I mark a chunk to extendable while adding a chunk to dbspace using onspaces command in Informix?

Tags: database, informix

I would like to know if I can mark a chunk to extendable while adding a chunk to a dbspace using the `onspaces` command itself. There is a column called **is_extendable** in the syschunks table in the sysmaster database. How do you enable it while adding a chunk to a dbspace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Automatic space management](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_1351.htm), it's only available since 11.70.

In particular, [Marking a chunk as extendable or non-extendable](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_1356.htm) indicates that you do not use `onspaces` but you use (for example) DB-Access to execute an administrative function:

> **To mark a chunk as extendable:**
>
> - Run the `admin()` or `task()` function with the modify chunk extendable argument, as follows:
>
>   ```
>     EXECUTE FUNCTION task("modify chunk extendable", "chunk number");
>   ```
>
> **To mark a chunk as not extendable:**
>
> - Run the `admin()` or `task()` function with the modify chunk extendable off argument, as follows:
>
>   ```
>     EXECUTE FUNCTION task("modify chunk extendable off", "chunk number");
>   ```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Leffler and Mr.Henriques , I presume to do anything in Informix with you two Informix wizards backing me